# One page CSS print preview

Tags: css

im using this CSS code to create a page like an A4 size paper

```
.box { width:700px; 
height:700px;
padding:30px;
border:1px solid black;
margin:1px;
display:table; }
```

my problem is:

when i print preview, even if i set settings of printer to reduce and fit, still it makes 2 pages, what script should i make so i can make a fix width and length the same as A4 size paper, i saw some articles that there is no specific pixels that equals to A4 size. but then i just want to make 1 page output.

Thanks.

Comment: Without having seen the current print preview (2 pages), try reducing the actual amount of content. You could also reduce the amount of spacing between elements and the font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use centimetres as size values in CSS as well as pixels.

```
height: 20cm;
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: i think i have the solution and it works, i use:
table {border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;}